# .innerHTML function Javascript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

This is my code:

```
function text(var text)
{
  var Value = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML;
  var New = Value + text;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=New;
}
```

What it's supposed to do is get a string from when it's called, and then add that string to the end of a div element with the ID "display". I called it like this: `text("hello");`

The HTML of the webpage is a blank div element, and it stays blank even after the code is run. It worked when I did `document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="hello!";`, but isn't now. Thanks!

Comment: ...so what's your question? I can't see what you need help with...

Comment: What behavior did you observe?

Comment: I'm sorry! :P The HTML of the webpage is a blank div element, and it stays blank even after the code is run. It worked when I did <code>document.getElementById("display").innerHTML="hello!";</code>, but isn't now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use "var" for a function parameter - just listing it between the function parenthesis is enough.  So change that function to:

```
function text(text)
{
  var Value = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML;
  var New = Value + text;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=New;
}
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Take the `var` out of the function parameter: `function text(text)...`

BTW: don't name your parameter the same thing as your function - it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

And you can do it like this:

```
function text(inputText)
{
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = document.getElementById("display").innerHTML +" "+ inputText;
}
```

:)